# Error installing Apache2 Server

Tags: 11.04, apache2

I'm trying to install `apache2` server, but it gives following error message:

> It looks like you've deleted `/etc/apache2/mods-available/cgid.load`, so `mod_cgid` cannot be enabled.
>
> To fix this, please purge and reinstall apache2.2-common.
>
> Setting up apache2 (2.2.17-1ubuntu1.5) ...

I've done the same using ubuntu software center, but getting the same error again.

Comment: It says `to fix this, please purge and reinstall apache2.2-common`. What happend after you did this?

Comment: it give this message: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apache2 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 335 not upgraded. but when i try "http://localhost" it doesn't give any output.

Comment: When tried to purge `apache2.2-common` does that finished properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to install apache2 , upgrade or restore it ?
this error is more of "reinstall" issue .

**ATTENTION IT IS A TRICK**

Using the console is more efficient

I suggest you to check if some dependency or file of `apache2` is still in your system

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep apache2.2-common
```

will list all the dependencies of `apache2.2-common` package, if any try to remove it manually. By,

```
sudo dpkg -r *dependency name*
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove *dependency name*
```

Once finished proceed to purge it,

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2.2-common
```

or at least try to touch the missing file to bypass the problem

```
touch /etc/apache2/mods-available/cgid.load
```

I'm sure you have also removed other files too, So proceed step by step on all your missing configurations