# Error installing Apache2 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apache2

I'm new to Ubuntu, I'd installed Apache2 in Ubuntu but due to errors during installation i uninstalled it. But when i try re-installing it again an error is displayed in terminal..

```
Error: Module cgid does not exixts.
It looks like you've deleted /etc/apache2/mods-available/cgid.load, so mod_cgid cannot be enabled. 
To fix this, please purge and reinstall apache2.2-commom. 
/etc/init.d/apache2: 51: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed..
```

Please help me to solve this error..

Comment: this should work: http://askubuntu.com/questions/279492/error-installing-apache2-server

Answer (score 0):

Try completely purging apache2, then try to re-install again.

`sudo apt-get remove apache2*`

[You can find the steps here...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176964/permanently-removing-apache2)